# Fazer uma requisição Ajax com RxJs em JS

Tags: ajax

Quero consultar uma API do gitHub e adquirir repositorios para fazer alguns mapeamentos, porem estou tendo problemas em fazer require com o ajax

```
const { XMLHttpRequest } = require('xmlhttprequest')
const { ajax } = require('rxjs/ajax')
const {map, concatAll} = require('rxjs/operators')

ajax({
    createXHR : () => new XMLHttpRequest(),
    url: 'https://api.github.com/users/cod3rcursos/repos'
})
    .pipe(
        map(resp =>JSON.parse( resp.xhr.responseText)),
    )
    .subscribe(console.log)
```

Retorna o seguinte:
[AjaxErrorImpl: aborted]

Answer (score -2):

O xmlhttprequest mudou. Troque para xhr2.
A reposta também está diferente. Vai ficar assim:

```
const { ajax } = require('rxjs/ajax')
const XMLHttpRequest = require("xhr2")

const { map, concatAll } = require('rxjs/operators')

ajax({
    createXHR: () => new XMLHttpRequest(),
    url: 'https://api.github.com/users/cod3rcursos/repos'
})
.pipe(
    map(resp => resp.response),
    concatAll(),
    map(repo => repo.full_name)
    )
    .subscribe(console.log)
```